# Forgotten culture from centuries

Tags: dharma, brahmins, teaching, dharma-shastras

Many people want to follow their culture as their ancestor was following centuries back.

But unfortunately they are not having enough knowledge about this, so they are forced to neglect and start preparing reasons for retreat/avoid.

Now we have a medium for vast community here, so I want to ask something which I need to follow in my future.

1. I want to start implementing daily Pooja. I am not a Brahmin. So is it possible to do daily pooja
2. Is there any list of ceremony which we need to follow for a child from day one?

Comment: 1)Not everyone can do  Pujas like a Vedic priest but everyone(Brahmin or Non Brahmin) has the right to do Puja.Hence,our scriptures allow us to do it "Yatha Shakti"(i.e as per our capabilities).So ,go ahead but do learn it from Guru or a learned priest.2)The Shastras recommend following the 16 Samskaras .You should ask a learned Vedic priest about this.